# How to boot Dell Latitude 5580 from USB?

Tags: boot, dell-latitude

How to boot Dell Latitude 5580 from USB?

I took an iso-burned DoK (disk on key) with Ubuntu 22.04 and plugged it to my Dell Latitude 5580.

I restarted several time; I tried to hit <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd> to boot from DoK or at least go into BIOS to check for booting from the DoK but nothing happened.

How to boot Dell Latitude 5580 from USB?

Comment: Just copying an ISO to a USB will not work.  The USB stick needs to be bootable.  If you are creating the stick from Windows, use rufus  http://rufus.ie/en/ , if from Linux, try etcher https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-a-bootable-linux-usb-drive/

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I had to click the <kbd>F2</kbd> of the leptop's own keyboard, not of the external keyboard I connected via USB.

Comment: The reason is that pre-boot the USB-drivers for your external keyboard are not yet loaded thus the signal sent to the laptop cannot be understood while the internal keyboard is connected directly to the motherboard.